# Osepp DS1307 RTC program error (tmElements_t tm; does not name a type)

Tags: programming, rtc

Using a basic 1307 SetTime program, and ran into a problem (first time programming a module).

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>

const char *monthName[12] = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};

tmElements_t tm;

void setup() {
  bool parse=false;
  bool config=false;

  // get the date and time the compiler was run
  if (getDate(__DATE__) && getTime(__TIME__)) {
    parse = true;
    // and configure the RTC with this info
    if (RTC.write(tm)) {
      config = true;
    }
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // wait for Arduino Serial Monitor
  delay(200);
  if (parse && config) {
    Serial.print("DS1307 configured Time=");
    Serial.print(__TIME__);
    Serial.print(", Date=");
    Serial.println(__DATE__);
  } else if (parse) {
    Serial.println("DS1307 Communication Error :-{");
    Serial.println("Please check your circuitry");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Could not parse info from the compiler, Time=\"");
    Serial.print(__TIME__);
    Serial.print("\", Date=\"");
    Serial.print(__DATE__);
    Serial.println("\"");
  }
}

void loop() {
}

bool getTime(const char *str)
{
  int Hour, Min, Sec;

  if (sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &Hour, &Min, &Sec) != 3) return false;
  tm.Hour = Hour;
  tm.Minute = Min;
  tm.Second = Sec;
  return true;
}

bool getDate(const char *str)
{
  char Month[12];
  int Day, Year;
  uint8_t monthIndex;

  if (sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", Month, &Day, &Year) != 3) return false;
  for (monthIndex = 0; monthIndex < 12; monthIndex++) {
    if (strcmp(Month, monthName[monthIndex]) == 0) break;
  }
  if (monthIndex >= 12) return false;
  tm.Day = Day;
  tm.Month = monthIndex + 1;
  tm.Year = CalendarYrToTm(Year);
  return true;
}
```

And I got the following

```
"tmElements_t tm;" does not name a type.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to example [ReadTest/ReadTest.ino](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/DS1307RTC/blob/master/examples/ReadTest/ReadTest.ino), you have to include

```
#include <TimeLib.h>
```

See also comment from Alexander below (unchecked by me) that Time.h needs to be referenced.

Comment: Added that to the code, and it tells me there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Maybe you used another library (you could try this one instead?) I never used this or the other library myself btw.

Comment: Arduino Studio also need to reference Time Library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used the right library, and it's in the Arduino library folder. Changed it to <TimeLib.h> and ran into the invalid library issue. I put on my TFT shield and tested the examples for that and it ran fine. Maybe something else that I am missing... First time wiring up a module.